# Как протестировать метод с имитацией ввода пользователем?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {
    private Scanner scanner;

    public Input(Scanner scanner) {
        this.scanner = scanner;
    }

    public int IputData(){
        int res = scanner.nextInt();
        return res*2;
    }
}
```

> > пробовал протестовать с помощью Mockito но выдает ошибку

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Scanner;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class InputTest {

    @Test
    public void iputData() {
        Scanner mock = mock(Scanner.class);
        when(mock.nextInt()).thenReturn(1);
        Input input = new Input(mock);
        assertEquals(2,input.IputData());
    }
}
```

Comment: Текст ошибки какой?

Comment: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class java.util.Scanner
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types

 at InputTest.iputData(InputTest.java:14)

Comment: я бы в таком случае написал бы просто декоратор вокруг сканнера и мокал декоратор

Answer (score 1):

Проще было бы не мокать `Scanner`, а создать его экземпляр, используя строку или строки, имитирующую ввод пользователя:

```java
@Test
public void inputData() {
    Scanner notMock = new Scanner("2");
    Input input = new Input(notMock);

    assertEquals(2, input.IputData());
}
```

В Junit 5 есть возможность задать массив строк для параметризованного теста:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {"   2   ", "2", "\t2"})
public void inputData(String userInput) {
    Scanner notMock = new Scanner(userInput);
    Input input = new Input(notMock);

    assertEquals(2, input.IputData());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно запустить одну программу при помощи другой программы, для этого подойдет `Process`:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Команда_запуска_String);
```

Затем используйте это для ввода/вывода:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream()); // Через этот writer можно ввоздить значения
Scanner errScanner = new Scanner(p.getErrorStream()); // Сканер потока ошибок (То что в Java System.err.println())
Scanner outScanner = new Scanner(p.getInputStream()); // Сканер потока ошибок (То что в Java System.out.println())

// Ввод строки
writer.println(input); 
writer.flush();
```

Если вы используйте Eclipse, то команду запуска можно посмотреть так:
Run >> Run Configurations... >> см картинку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

#### Пример:

#### `MyRunner.java`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

...

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("путь_до_javaw.exe -Dfile.encoding=Cp1251 -classpath \"ПУТЬ\\eclipse-stackoverflow\\1350994\\bin\" Main");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream()); // Через этот writer можно ввоздить значения
        Scanner errScanner = new Scanner(p.getErrorStream()); // Сканер потока ошибок (То что в Java System.err.println())
        Scanner outScanner = new Scanner(p.getInputStream()); // Сканер потока ошибок (То что в Java System.out.println())

        writer.println(10); // вводим число 10
        writer.flush();

        
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                if(errScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.err.println(errScanner.nextLine());
                }
            }
        }).start();
        
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                if(outScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println(outScanner.nextLine());
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

#### Main .java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Result:");
        System.out.println(i * i);
        System.err.println("0 Errors");
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете все соединить потому что я не совсем понимаю как это должно работать?

Comment: добавил в ответ